# wordpress css loaded into page overriding main css

Tags: css, wordpress, alignment

I have my css and html set to center align on the right side bar of my site.
However when I load the blog it also loads the css which goes with the theme
and it is moving my images to the left on the side bar to the right.

See it live here: http://www.edvizenor.com/?p=blog&id=102

How can I fix the images so they do not align on the left when I 
load the blog content.

You can see if you click on other links above to see that the images then go to the center
again.

My css loads from a link like this:

```
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

My Wordpress content loads from this code below. But I don't know
how it includes its own css with the theme. There is no way for me to show
this code as I don't know how it loads. I can only show how I load the wordpress content 
and it is done like this:

```
<?
if(!$_GET[id])
{


$posts = get_posts();

foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>

  <br />
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="blogHolder" name="blogHolder" >
  <tr>
    <td width="21%" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">


    <div class="blogImage"><a href="http://www.EdVizenor.com/?p=blogContent&id=<? echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><? echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], array(133,133) ); ?></a></div> 

    <div class="blogDate">
    <table width="217" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="76"><? echo the_date();?></td>

    </tr>
</table>


    </div>    



    <img src="http://www.TimStaples.com/images/blogImageBox.png" width="177" height="177" /></td>
    <td width="79%" height="27"  valign="middle" class="blogTitle"><? echo the_title(); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td  valign="top" background="http://www.TimStaples.com/images/blogBG2.png"><div class="blogContent">
      <? echo the_excerpt(); ?>

    <div class="readMore"><a href="http://www.EdVizenor.com/?p=blogContent&id=<? echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><img src="http://www.TimStaples.com/images/readMore.png" width="142" height="32" alt="Read More" /></a> </div>

    </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    </tr>
</table>
        <p>



<?php
endforeach;

}

if($_GET[id])
{
    $posts = get_posts('p=' . $_GET[id] .'');

    foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
          <tr>
            <td align="right"><?php the_date(); ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="middle" class="blogTitlePrint"><br />
              <?php the_title(); ?>
              <hr /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><?php the_content(); ?></td>
          </tr>


        </table>
    <br />

<?php
    endforeach;
}
?>
```

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — **and include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. (But I didn't -1, as its still well described!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to your table that holds the elements in your right sidebar. I'm calling it "side-table".
In your css add the following:

```
.side-table p { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: THAT DID IT! I knew it was something simple like this. Many thanks to you @Mihai!